# Formatting legend item and feature count text in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, legend, feature-count

In ArcGIS Pro you can turn on the option "Show feature counts" in Format legend item -> Feature Display Options to show the number of features for each legend item. However, when turned on, the number is put right after the legend item,  without any spaces, like this: motorway245.

Instead I'd like either a space between the two, or better, put the feature count in parentheses like this:

> motorway (245).

Is there any way to do this in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.3.3.

Open the Legend Properties and click Show Properties under Legend Items:

[image]

There you can use the Feature Display Options to check the box to Show feature counts and type " (" before count and ")" after it:

[image]