# Show feature count as percentage in the legend

Tags: arcgis-pro, legend

Similar to [Formatting legend item and feature count text in ArcGIS Pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327378) ,is there a way to show the feature count as percentage (like 45%) in the legend?

Comment: Short answer is no